# laser scanner or depth camera

Tags: ros, kinect, depth-image, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is an affordable (good enough quality) laser scanner or depth camera (to support navigation, path planning, and obstacle avoidance)?  we plan to buy a few hundred units.

currently, we're using kinect for our prototype.  did anyone use kinect for final product?  would microsoft sell a few hundred kinects at a time at bulk pricing?

or is there an alternative product ou there that is more suitable for mass production vs prototyping?

any recommendation is much appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182923/laser-scanner-or-depth-camera/) by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-03**:
Define affordable and your requirements (e.g. 2D vs. 3D). From a research perspective the smallest Hokuyo around $1000 is very affordable and considered cheap and that's only 2D data. If you think Kinect is already too much, you might need to go down with your expectations.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-03**:
My feeling says that lasers are usually more expensive than (depth) cameras. If those are still too much, maybe look into some other sensor modalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some dash cam applications that use OpenCV on raspberry pi that seem to do a good job, regarding depth measurement of objects.

Might be an alternative, but will not really work as a scanner.

---

Originally posted by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) with karma: 255 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0